# Vim - automatic open close braces and move cursor

Tags: linux, vim, indentation, vi

I'm new to Vim and right now i just need a very simple thing:

```
(1)public class Foo <open brace><hit ENTER> 
or
(2)public class Foo <hit ENTER><open brace><hit ENTER>
```

To get this

```
(1)public class Foo{
   |cursor here
}
```

or

```
 (2)public class Foo
 {
    |cursor here
 }
```

My .vimrc is:

```
set smartindent
set shiftwidth=4
set number
inoremap { {<CR>}<Left>
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: how about autoclose plugin? https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want: "smart" plugins like [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009) or [DelimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) or simpler custom mappings. Here is one way to do #1 but one could find many alternatives (I've had a few in `~/.vimrc`):

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>==<C-o>O
```

And here is a variation for #2:

```
inoremap {{ <CR>{<CR>}<C-o>==<C-o>O
```

But I'd suggest, if you didn't do it already, to try [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) or [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). Both allow you to expand snippets and are *very* useful when writing lots of boilerplate. For example,

```
cla<Tab>
```

could become:

```
public class Foo
{
    |
}
```

Think about all the keypresses you'd save!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>%</kbd> (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) will find bracket set of some functions.